# mount server as drive

Tags: windows, networking, mount, remote-access

Is there a way to mount a server to a drive letter in Windows? I know a compareable software called [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/). I really like the idea. and was wondering if anyone knows ways to do this type of thing in windows?

I'm using windows XP

Comment: What do you mean by map the server? If you mean just the a certain drive or folder on the server then yes

Comment: I know how to map network drives. But can the same be done for a server? (You can view the link I provided as a comparable program. It's exactly what I'd like) I would like to in theory, connect to my dev server but have it in "My Computer" as its own drive letter.

Comment: What do you mean by "a server"? SSH access?

Comment: it would be a linux server. FTP, or SSH is what I could use.

Comment: Sorry for just a link, but as I'm still not 100% sure of the issue, you can use this: http://www.wealthyaffiliaterevolution.com/how-to-map-a-remote-server-to-a-drive-in-windows-explorer/ (if it helps I'll move it to an answer)

Comment: This works to a point. Thank you. I am able to map the folder, but it does not appear as a network drive letter.  C: D: E: etc... This is the main feature I need. All that your tutorial created was a web folder. I need a drive letter.

Comment: Must be something to do with the config on my machine. I can only map a web folder. can't make it a drive letter. My machine probably needs an update or something, but it's locked down so I can't. I'll try this at home later on my Win7 machine and see if it works. If it does I'll mark answer solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've been looking for.
The solutions given did allow me to map to a web folder, but did not give me the drive letter. Having a web folder is only really a shortcut to FTP. I am unable to save changes to the web folder. I have to save them locally, then upload.

With these types of tools, you can open the files and when you save them, the changes are reflected on the server.

http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/winindex.html
http://www.expandrive.com/

Answer (score 3):

Mapping drives is a standard feature of Windows networking.

There are many ways to make a drivemapping one is to

- open a Command Prompt windows
- type `net use X: \\servername\sharename`

The full syntax is

```
 NET USE [devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
    [/USER:[domainname\]username]
```

On the server, if Windows, you can use Windows Explorer to select a folder and share it (use the right-click context-menu)

If you don't belong to a Windows Domain (you'd know if you did) you just have to make sure both computers are in the same workgroup and (ideally) have the same usernames and (ideally) passwords.

Comment: What if it's a linux server? Will the same work?

Comment: @Frantumn: The client side command is the same, you may need to specify  the username and password on the command line if they are different. Configuring the shared folder on the Linux server is done by installing SAMBA, editing it's configuration file and starting (or restarting) the samba service - details depend on Linux distribution and release. Some years ago you had to configure Windows to allow plain-text passwords (or something similar) but this may no longer be necessary.

Comment: Must be something to do with the config on my machine. I can only map a web folder. can't make it a drive letter. My machine probably needs an update or something, but it's locked down so I can't. I'll try this at home later on my Win7 machine and see if it works. If it does I'll mark answer solved.

Answer (score 1):

[win-sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) is capable of mounting a remote server's filesystem via SSH and mapping it to a drive letter. This is not for the faint of heart, though. There's almost no documentation (and I don't have time to write it :) ).